# How to retrieve value of a function in R

Tags: r, function

when calling a function in R, how can I retrieve the result values. For example, I used 'roc' function and I need to extract AUC value and CI (0.6693 and 0.6196-0.7191 respectively in the following example).

```
> roc(tmpData[,lenCnames], fitted(model), ci=TRUE)

Call:
roc.default(response = tmpData[, lenCnames], predictor = fitted(model),     ci = TRUE)

Data: fitted(model) in 127 controls (tmpData[, lenCnames] 0) < 3248 cases (tmpData[, lenCnames] 1).
Area under the curve: 0.6693
95% CI: 0.6196-0.7191 (DeLong)
```

I can use the following to fetch these values with associated texts.

```
> z$auc
Area under the curve: 0.6693
> z$ci
95% CI: 0.6196-0.7191 (DeLong)
```

Is there a way to get only the values and not the text.

I do now how to get these using 'regular expression' or 'strsplit' function, but I suspect there should be some other way to directly access these values.

Comment: pROC package from r cran

Comment: Would be nice to have a reproducible example with a sample dataset included. This will help us to make the answers more valuable.

Comment: @Arun, thanks as.numeric worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's helpful to use reproducible examples when asking a question. Also best to refer to the library you're asking about ("pROC"), since it is not loaded with base R. `pROC` has functions that extract `auc` and `ci.auc` objects from the `roc` object.

```
>library("pROC")
>data(aSAH)
# Basic example
>z <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b,
    levels=c("Good", "Poor"))

# Examining the class of 'auc' output shows us that it is also of class 'numeric'
> class(auc(z))
[1] "auc"     "numeric"
# calling 'as.numeric' will extract the value
> as.numeric(auc(z))
[1] 0.7313686

# calling 'as.numeric' on the 'ci.auc' object extracts three values.
as.numeric(ci(z))
[1] 0.6301182 0.7313686 0.8326189

# The ones we want are 1 and 3
> as.numeric(ci(z))[c(1,3)]
[1] 0.6301182 0.8326189
```

Using the functions `str`, `class`, and `attributes` will often help you figure out how to get what you want out of an object.